# I have an error while compiling the substrate node

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, ink, substrate-contracts-node

I got this error after trying to install the substrate-contract-node :

#### 1) I download  rustc

```shell
rustc --version
rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
```

#### 2) I cloned the repo

I followed the instruction to install substrate-contract-node [here](https://docs.substrate.io/install/linux/)

```shell
git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
```

#### 3) then I tried to compile the repo by this commands

```shell
git switch -c my-wip-branch
cargo build --release
```

and then I got this long error

```
failed to run custom build command for `sc-network-light v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/mohamed/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/sc-network-light-0fea2d72bbd5faeb/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /home/mohamed/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/prost-build-0.11.9/src/lib.rs:1457:10:
  Could not find `protoc` installation and this build crate cannot proceed without
      this knowledge. If `protoc` is installed and this crate had trouble finding
      it, you can set the `PROTOC` environment variable with the specific path to your
      installed `protoc` binary.If you're on debian, try `apt-get install protobuf-compiler` or download it from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

  For more information: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc

  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

so how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: You need to install the protobuf compiler for your system.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, it seems your system is missing the protobuf compiler. You need to get it for your OS. You can look at the setup here for the necessary packages before compiling : https://github.com/paritytech/extended-parachain-template/blob/main/docs/rust-setup.md